# mergExt Help needed with installing externals

Tags: livecode

I can't get a Mac standalone to include the latest (March 2015) Commercial mergJSON external.

In this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGI8V.jpg

you can see the Windows version correctly includes the mergJSON DLL and the revxml DLL.

But the Mac package is missing the mergJSON.bundle but does include the xml bundle.

Also pictured is the My LiveCode folder.

The externals are in My LiveCode > Externals and the Runtime folders. 
The Externals.txt files are identical in all folders and contain "mergJSON,mergJSON.bundle" in the OS X versions.

The version is LC 6.7.3.

mergJSON works beautifully in the IDE.
The stack is Monte's *mergJSON.livecode* demo file with the revxml external added.

There is an odd error when compiling:

*1  File to include in standalone not found: "/movioke folder//Users/montegoulding/Dropbox/mergJSON/binaries/mergJSON.lcext"*

I followed the lesson "How To Install 3rd Party Externals For Use in the IDE and Standalone Builder", which seems out of date.
It would be nice if RunRev fully documented the ideal file structure of externals and plugins folders.

Also, *answer the externalcommands of stack "revExternalLibrary"* only shows the xml commands when called by the mac standalone.

Help much appreciated.

Thanks,
Jim Lambert

Answer (score 1):

Well, I answer my own question!

I had foolishly created an incorrect folder structure under *My LiveCode*.

My LiveCode > Runtime > Mac OS X > **Externals > Universal**

is dead wrong. When I changed it to

My LiveCode > Runtime > Mac OS X > **Universal > Externals**

the externals copied to the standalone correctly.

Hopefully others may learn from my error.

Thanks.